# Trigger Gitlab Pipeline when any file in directory change or any sub directory inside sub directory give directory changes

Tags: gitlab, cicd

I am having directory structure as below.

Gitlab pipeline to trigger pipeline when any changes done in `abc` dir or any sub-directory or any of its sub sub directoty inside it.

So If any changes happened in directory or sub directory or  sub of sub directory, Gitlab Trigger pipeline should trigger.

Sample paths:

path: `abc/hi/hey/get/ok.txt`

path: `abc/hi/hello/pli/vet.txt`

path: `abc/xcd.txt`

Current .gitlab-ci.yml

```
only:
        changes:
            - "abc/*"
```

I want to check any changes in sub directory and sub sub director of all above `paths`.I made changes as below.Will this work, or any other changes are required?

New .gitlab-ci.yml

```
only:
        changes:
            - "abc/**/*"
            - "abc/*"
```

Ref link-
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlychanges--exceptchanges

https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-trigger-a-child-pipeline-when-changes-to-any-files-in-sub-directories-in-a-specified-branch-alone/48973/2

Comment: why don't you try it out with a dummy project? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [only/except documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#onlychanges--exceptchanges) which you've linked, you'll notice an example on how to trigger a job for changes

> a directory and all its subdirectories, for example `path/to/directory/**/*`.

So in your example, you should only need the one line:

`- abc/**/*`

Comment: But I have multiple sub directories inside sub directories, if anything changes in sub of sub directories will this work?

Comment: it's supposed to work for all subdirectories, I didn't try it yesterday when posting the answer, but I have had it work in the past